# Converting a string to a double

Tags: c#, .net, string, double, globalization

I'm trying to convert a string to a double value but it's not returning me what I expect...

```
double dbl;
Double.TryParse("20.0", out dbl);
```

That piece of code is returning 200.0 (instead of 20.0) as a double value. Any idea why?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should pass `InvariantCulture` to the method.

The reason behind this is that your regional settings probably set `.` as separator character and not decimal point.

```
double.TryParse("20.0", NumberStyles.Any, 
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out x);
```